How would cybernetic implants be integrated into the human body to work in a plausibly or semi plausible way?
I am interested in writing a sci-fi cyberpunk story set in circa 2030 CE.
Background
In my story, a company specializes in "cybernetic surgery", adding cybernetic implants to humans, like cybernetic limbs and/or organs like bionic hearts or eyes. Through it is not widespread and only 20-25% use it.
Problem
There is lots of conflicting information on Google Scholar concerning how cybernetic implants would be integrated into the human body.
Some have suggested directly grafting the implant to the bone and the nerves, others say you just need to craft a “connection port” on the damaged side of the body for the implant to connect with it, and some say that you don't need to connect the implant to the nerves and that the signals of a Brain-Computer Interface (BCI) relaying information to the implant is sufficient without using nerves as a substrate.
Most seem to agree that a form of Brain-Computer Interface (BCI) would be needed to be installed in the brain to control the implant.
Question
Assuming that the technology and knowledge needed for this scenario to work exist in a near future (2030 CE onwards):
What would be needed to be done to integrate cybernetic implants into the human body and work in a plausible or semi plausible way?

Welcome user 110409. Interesting set of questions, but please note we deal with a single focused question per post. You can ask more questions, each in their own threads and link to this one if you like, but please [edit] to limit this to just the one for starters.

This seems a lot like "please design me some cybernetic implants" which isn't really a question. Consider asking about a specific issue you're having with your own ideas or research, like what power supplies might be practical.

You are correct, I will edict the question to be more specific

Your problem isn't the surgery. The "nanomedicine drug to control body rejections of foreign object" and interfacing to the nervous system that works as well as natural organs are things that we don't have and don't look likely to have working well in 2030. "Realistic" is off the table.

"What surgery process would be needed: Step 1. Make a smaller or a larger cut, depending on the size of the implant, or possibly remove a limb etc. Step 2. Insert or attach said implant using the appropriate tools and procedures, as per the installation or implantation instructions of the manufacturer. Step 3. Make necessary sutures, possibly under a microscope, sprinkle magic powder, close the incision. Step 4. Hope for the best.

Minor point: 20-25% adoption is not "not widespread".  There is one personal computer for every four people on the planet (ie. approximately 25% adoption), and no one would argue that PCs are not widespread.

Hi, there are bio-neutral materials like titan-porcelain, that grow into bone. They have problems though- they are heavy in thus, deform the bone. They are non-regenerating, thus minor fractures stay. Neural interfaces only work temporary, as they create scar tissue around the material and then cease working. Thats the fate of all those quadriplegic "man walks again" implant studies.

So the ideal implant - is a cancer, that produces and repairs a bio-synthetic organ and reforms once damaged, exactly as expected. You get a cell donation, and then you grow a usb port in your skull. And you pray to the gods it stays there. You don't want a dongle on your dangle. Then again, if you get yourself connected..

VTR. This question has been sufficiently edited to be answerable.

I believe this still goes against the "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." guideline in the Don't Ask part of the Help section. Can you let us know what you have considered yourself already? Have you looked up any resources concerning implants? What level of plausibility do you hope to get from an answer? Finally: have you played Deus Ex? :)

Yes, I have played Deus Ex. The reason why I wish to use a "Nanomachine Drug" made of the stem cell of the cybernetic user is cause to prevent the build-up of scar tissue that blocks electrical signals between implant and human tissue. I am agaisnt some terminology in Deus Ex since they use terms like "Rejection Syndrome" cause that is not a syndronme that is just your body rejecting a foreign object. I preffer cyberpunk 2007/edgerunner take on the drugs needed to supress the body´s defenses agaisnt foreign objects
